# Find the limit of $\sum\limits_{n=0}^\infty \frac{n}{3^n}$

Tags: sequences-and-series, analysis, convergence-divergence

Hi all What would the best way/method be to approach this, any advice would be appreciated

Comment: Binomial theorem might help

Comment: Thank you very much @Travis Ive got it now

Comment: I wonder how  the binomial theorem can help here.

Comment: @Kimo You're welcome, I'm glad you found the link useful.

Comment: @Timbuc you can see the answer below which has an expansion of 1 over 1-x.

Comment: @user291957, that's the expansion of a function  in a power series. What that has to do with the binomial theorem, which states that $$\forall\,a,b\in\Bbb R\,,\,n\in\Bbb N\;,\;\;(a+b)^n=\sum_{k=0}^n\binom nk a^{n-k}b^k\;?$$ While certainly one can try to expand that theorem to the case where $\;n\notin\Bbb N\;$, that's not usually known as "the binomial theorem", imo.

Answer (score 1):

Notice:

$$ \frac{1}{1-x} = \sum x^n $$

By Abel's theorem, we can differentiate the series, and we obtain

$$ \frac{1}{(1-x)^2} = \sum n x^{n-1}$$

Now, you should conclude.

Comment: The derivative should be without the minus sign.